# request in node works but in js (vue) doesnt

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

Hi I have a backend which receive a request with a picture and storage, I try it with postman and with the code below and works perfectly

```
var axios = require('axios')
var FormData = require('form-data')
var fs = require('fs')
var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', fs.createReadStream('index.png'))
console.log('HEADERS')
console.log(data.getHeaders())
let config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:5013/v1/business/honda/widget/test/',
  headers: {
    ...data.getHeaders(),
  },
  data: data,
}
```

The problem is in my vue app I try to do it with the next code, I have 2 buttons with one load the image and the other to send it.
In the back end I have the follow error when try to pick 'file'

*http: no such file*

```
 let imageData
//send the image to backend
    function funtest() {
      console.log('image')

      const formData = new FormData()
      const url = 'http://localhost:5013/v1/business/honda/widget/test/'

      formData.append('file', imageData)
      let config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        data: formData,
      }
      axios(config)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('RESPONSE')
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('ERROR')
          console.log(error)
        })
    }

//function to read the image 
    function onImage(data) {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        imageData = e.target.result
        console.log('imagen')
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(data.target.files[0])
    }
```

Comment: FileReader is to load local files. You need to request it with Axios first.

Comment: This is just the functions, I use it in my web so with the first I load the picture and show a preview (works) and after fill a form is send with the funtest() function

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably not reading the path to `index.png` file correctly here, `fs.createReadStream('index.png')`

Consider using `path` like this

```js
const path = require('path');

const filePath = path.join(__dirname,  'index.png');

data.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filePath))
```

NB: This is just a quick and dirty suggestion, and it's not guaranteed to work but it's definitely worth a shot

Comment: The problem was with browser, not Node part

Comment: Exactly, the node part work fine, in the Browser I show the picture like a preview before send it